# PHP - Transformar objeto em array

Tags: php, array, stdclass

Preciso transformar um objeto em array para poder percorre-lo e extrair seus dados, até consigo com:

```
   $array = (array) $object;
```

Mas o resultado com um `var_dump($array)` é o seguinte, de forma que não consigo percorre-lo com um *foreach*:

```
array(1) {
  ["Clientedata"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(4) "Nome"
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "usuario@dominio.com"
    ["celular"]=>
    string(15) "(00) 00000-0000"
  }
}
```

Pretendo percorrer o array da seguinte forma:

```
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        echo "$key: $value";
    }
```

Assim apenas obtenho um erro: `Notice:  Array to string conversion in ...` E o retorno: `Clientedata: Array`

Comment: Como você está percorrendo esse array? Se possível [edit] sua pergunta e adicione seu código.

Comment: Pelo que vi e multidimensional. O foreach vai percorrer a primeira dimensão. Se quer percorrer  a segunda dimensão deve colocar foreach dentro de foreach. É assim por diante. Ou especificar a dimensão que quer percorrer informando a chave da dimensão.

Comment: O que não compreendo é o porquê, já que se eu crio um objeto com stdClass e o transformo em array consigo percorre-lo normalmente.

Comment: O que acontece nesse erro aí é que a primeira dimensão não contém valores para serem impressos como string. Você deve agora entrar na segunda dimensão. Lá o de você pediu pra imprimir a $key ele até imprime. Mais $value é um outro array. Que é a segunda dimensão. Para você visualizar ele você deve fazer assim print_r($value) ou var_dump($value).

Comment: Mas independente do porquê, consegui percorrer a "segunda dimensão" com outro foreach.

Comment: Mas porque essa primeira dimensão é criada?

Comment: Não sei de onde tá pegando esse dado. Mais isso é muito usado quando se quer separar dados por dimensões. Tipo na primeira dimensão tem número de ordens de serviço. Aí na segunda dimensão pode ter N array contendo a identificação de cada dados do cliente, dados da ordem, dados da empresa  e na terceira dimensão pode ter os dados de cada um dos itens da segunda dimensão como nome do cliente, cpf, etc. entendeu?

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.

Comment: Agora que vi. Acesse os dados da seguinte maneira. echo $value->nome; echo $value->email; E pode fazer o foreach sem chave também. Tipo foreach($array as $a){ echo $a->nome; }

Comment: Isso não é uma coleção para você percorrer!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a função `get_object_vars` ela retorna todas as propriedades públicas de um dado objeto em formato de `array` associativo.

```
$foo = get_object_vars($object);

var_dump($foo);
// Resultado
array(3) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(4) "Nome"
    ["email"]=>
    string(19) "usuario@dominio.com"
    ["celular"]=>
    string(15) "(00) 00000-0000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para percorrer um *array multidimensional* basta utilizar foi `foreach`, ou passar o índice no `foreach`. Ex:

```
foreach($array['Clientedata'] as $key => $value){
    echo "$key: $value";
}
```

Caso você não saiba o nome do índice, basta utilizar a função `end` ou `reset` para capturar o último ou o primeiro elemento do array respectivamente.

```
$novoArray = reset($array);

foreach($novoArray as $key => $value){
    echo "$key: $value";
}
```

Você provavelmente está recebendo esse array multidimensional pois seu objeto deve está armazenando esses valores na variável `Clientedata`. Ex:

```
<?php

class Cliente {
    public $Clientedata;

    public function __construct($nome, $email, $celular) {
        $this->Clientedata = [
            "nome"    => $nome,
            "email"   => $email,
            "celular" => $celular,
        ];
    }
}

$obj = new Cliente("Cliente", "cliente@email.com", "123456789");

var_dump( (array) $obj );
```

Answer (score 0):

Para transformar um objeto em array podemos usar a função `json_decode()` passando o segundo parâmetro como `true` que ele converte automaticamente para um array. ficaria algo como

```
$meuArray = json_decode($object,true);
```

Comment: Isso não vai funcionar porque a função `json_decode` recebe uma `string` como primeiro parâmetro.

Answer (score -1):

Mas no caso, você não tem uma coleção para percorrer, por isso não consegue percorrê-lo, para acessar os dados após converter em array bastaria fazer isso:

```
echo $array["Clientedata"]["nome"] . '\n<br>' .
     $array["Clientedata"]["email"] . '\n<br>' .
     $array["Clientedata"]["celular"];
```

Para acessar diretamente do objeto:

```
echo $objeto->Clientedata->nome . '\n<br>' .
     $objeto->Clientedata->email . '\n<br>' .
     $objeto->Clientedata->celular;
```

Se `Clientedata` fosse uma coleção, você poderia fazer destas duas formas:

a) Você não precisaria necessariamente convertê-lo em array para percorrê-lo, mas se você prefere percorrer em modo de array, bastaria fazer assim:

```
 $array = (array) $objeto;
    
    if (count($array['Clientedata'])) {
        foreach($array['Clientedata'] as $key => $value){
            echo  $value['nome'] . '<br>\n';
            echo  $value['email'] . '<br>\n';
            echo $value['celular'];
        }
    }
```

b) No caso de objeto, é so fazer um implement do Countable na sua classe:

```
//No php 7, essa função deve existir, mas se não existir ela é criada abaixo:
    if (!function_exists('is_countable')) {
        function is_countable($value): bool
        {
           return is_array($value) || (is_object($value) && $value instanceof Countable);
        }
     }
       //então vc checa se o elemento possui uma coleção: 
       if (is_contable($objeto->Clientedata)) {
           //e percorre ele...
           foreach( $objeto->Clientedata as $key => $value){
                echo  $value->nome . '<br>\n';
                echo  $value->email. '<br>\n';
                echo $value->celular;
            }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Simples e pratico...

```
foreach($array as $element){
    $result[$element[Clientedata]][] = $element;
}

$data[];
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
   $data[] = ['Clientedata' => $key,
             'item' =>$value
       ];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia.

```
    $meuArray = json_decode($object,true);
```

O trecho acima funcionou pra mim, porém vc precisa usar o json_encode primeiro.

```
    $object = json_encode($object);
    $meuArray = json_decode($object,true);
```